# React-redux: how do I get option value to show in a Select?

Tags: reactjs

I am practicing react and redux for a school project, building a todo app, and I have difficulties getting the option value to print. All that is rendered is an empty select drop down. Can anyone give a hint on what I have done wrong? I tried console.logging onSelectChange but it does not work, user can't choose anything.

```
  const AddTodo = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const id = uuidv4()

  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState('')
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('')

  const options = [
    {value: 'Home', label: 'Home'},
    {value: 'Work', label: 'Work'},
    {value: 'Studies', label: 'Studies'},
    {value: 'Love', label: 'Love'},
    {value: 'Hobbies', label: 'Hobbies'},
    {value: 'Other', label: 'Other'}
  ]

  const onSelectChange = (optionSelected) => {
    setCategory(optionSelected.value)
  }
  
  const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

    if (newTodo && category !== '') {
      dispatch(
        todos.actions.addToDo({
          id,
          description: newTodo,
          category,
          isComplete: false,
        })
      )
      setNewTodo('') // clear input 
      setCategory('') // clear category
    } else {
      alert ('Please type your todo and/or select a category first')
    } 
    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        maxLength="40"
        placeholder="Add your todo..."
        onChange={(event) => setNewTodo(event.target.value)}
        value={newTodo}        
      >
      </textarea>
      <button 
        type='submit'
      > 
          +
      </button>
      <div>
      <Label>Set category:</Label>
        <Select
          value={category.value}
          onChange={onSelectChange}
          options={options} 
          placeholder="Select a category"
        />
        </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some parts of your code you are assuming that `category` is a `string` which is the `value` of the selected option.  In other places you are assuming that `category` is an `object` and you are accessing `category.value` to get the value.

I cannot help you completely without knowing where this `Select` component comes from because different packages define their props differently.  So I don't know which one is the mistake.

You are assuming `string` in all but one place so I would start by changing `value={category.value}` to `value={category}` because `category` is already just the value.

If that doesn't work, look at the docs for the `value` and `onChange` props and make sure that what you are providing matches what is expected.  You need `onChange` to be with the option (not the event).  Is it?